# java, set bit values on hex number

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation

Given an arbitrary hex number which has 12 digits, what is the fastest way to set the n-th digit value? For example,

```
0x100000000000
```

how to set the 10th digit to 2, that is, 102000000000.

After checking the java doc, I think the number can be defined in java as

```
int hex = 0x100000000000;
```

and I need to convert it to 0x102000000000. I try to avoid to use any existing classes such as BitSet, since the code has to be written in both java and plain javascript. Thanks

Comment: If it's in hex, it's not a 12-bit number you have, but a 48-bit number. A 12-bit number in hex would be 3 characters long, like `0x100`.

Comment: I removed the java syntax. Now it's just a hex number in 12-bit.

Comment: @CMZS You should leave the `0x` at least. It's confusing otherwise.

Comment: I have changed the problem description. It is a hex number that has 12 digits. Each of the digit may have value from 0 to F.

Comment: How is the value being stored? A raw data, a BigInt, a String, other? We need a bit more information before we can help further.

Comment: There is really no such thing as a "hex number" in Java (and most languages). It's just one of the ways to write down am integral constant, it's not it's own special type that "keeps being a hex number". So setting a bit in "a hex number" is just setting a bit in an `int` or `long` or whatever

Comment: An `int` would not be big enough, as it is only 32 bits long.

Comment: I suggest you use the term hexit or nybble instead of digit when talking about hex numbers, as they're less ambiguous than digit. Also you should prefer zero-based numbering for consistency with how bits are usually numbered, so the 2 in `0x102000000000` is hexit 9, not 10.

Comment: Thank you very much for all you guy's suggestions. It's a great help for me to check my design on the data structure for the problem.

Comment: By the way, you can't do bit manipulation on such large values in Java*Script*. Doing bit manipulation on JavaScript numbers forces them to 32-bit, so you'll need to store your number as a string there, and do string manipulation instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in Java using bitwise operators. It should be very similar in Javascript.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long hex = 0x2222222222222222L;

    System.out.printf("0x%x", replaceDigit(hex, 10, 1));
}

public static long replaceDigit(long originalValue, int digitPosition, int replacementDigit)
{
    // Clear the 4 bits (i.e. 1 digit) at the position requested
    originalValue &= ~(0x0FL << digitPosition * 4);

    // Now put the replacement value at the position requested
    originalValue |= (long) replacementDigit << digitPosition * 4;

    return originalValue;
}
```

Comment: 'digit' is a singularly confusing choice of arg name there. pos/position maybe? it's definitely not a digit.

Comment: I've clarified the argument names